# Restricting list address who can send email from server

Tags: postfix, smtp, ovh

i want to restrict only a specific list from my Ubuntu system running Postfix to send emails,
of course i could receive external email ( sender/recipient)

supposing my domain name is `tt.net`

here's what i'v received from my host OVH ::

```
Our Antispam protection has detected a large amount of spam being sent from one of your IPs:
149.202.xx.xx

In order to ensure the security of our network the outgoing traffic from your server to
ports 25 has been suspended.

In order for you to check, here is a sample of the blocked emails:


  Destination IP: 185.34.84.134 - Message-ID: EC184031-4C36-4AB2-BB00-C456D4C38849@tt.net - Spam score: 300
Destination IP: 185.34.84.134 - Message-ID: EC184031-4C36-4AB2-BB00-C456D4C38849@tt.net - Spam score: 300
Destination IP: 185.34.84.134 - Message-ID: EC184031-4C36-4AB2-BB00-C456D4C38849@tt.net - Spam score: 300
Destination IP: 185.34.84.134 - Message-ID: EC184031-4C36-4AB2-BB00-C456D4C38849@tt.net - Spam score: 300
Destination IP: 185.34.84.134 - Message-ID: EC184031-4C36-4AB2-BB00-C456D4C38849@tt.net - Spam score: 300
Destination IP: 185.34.84.134 - Message-ID: EC184031-4C36-4AB2-BB00-C456D4C38849@tt.net - Spam score: 300
Destination IP: 185.34.84.134 - Message-ID: EC184031-4C36-4AB2-BB00-C456D4C38849@tt.net - Spam score: 300
Destination IP: 185.34.84.134 - Message-ID: EC184031-4C36-4AB2-BB00-C456D4C38849@tt.net - Spam score: 300
```

those adressess are not mine !! and are not configured on my virtual list.

main.cf ::

```
default_destination_rate_delay = 2
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_size_limit = 0
myhostname = smtp.tt.net
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =  permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/webmail.tt.net/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/webmail.tt.net/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_transport =  dovecot
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail/vmail
smtpd_recipient_limit = 5000
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1

smtpd_sender_restrictions =
   permit_mynetworks
   permit_sasl_authenticated
   reject_unknown_sender_domain
   reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname
   reject_unknown_client_hostname
smtpd_helo_required = yes

smtpd_helo_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    reject_invalid_helo_hostname
    reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
    reject_unknown_helo_hostname
```

master.cf ( part )

```
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

how can i restrict email sender from my server ?

Comment: Restrict??? OVH is telling you that you are sending out SPAM. I would be looking to see if that was true and if so, what was causing it, since it sounds like you may have a compromised system.